# HTML select multiple in Edge doesn't allow mouse click&drag to select multiple items

Tags: html-select, microsoft-edge

HTML `<select multiple="multiple">` allows mouse click&drag to select multiple items. It works in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer, but it doesn't work in Edge. Is anything missing? How do I make it work in Edge?

[example](https://codepen.io/pavelhodek/pen/xxKWdWp)

Answer (score 1):

First press the [ALT key] **or** [CTRL key] + try to drag the mouse pointer will help you to select multiple options in MS Edge browser.

[image]

Edit:

I notice that same code is working and user able to drag and select the options without using ALT or CTRL key in **Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0**.

I am able to produce this issue in **Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0**. Pressing the  [ALT key] **or** [CTRL key] + dragging the mouse pointer can be the work around for the issue.